# Set-Cookie Header is in the response but browser doesn't set Cookie in next request only in case of nginx router use

Tags: curl, cookies, nginx, google-chrome-devtools, http-redirect

Problem:
Browser requests which are part of a flow in order as seen via chrome developer tools:

1. /request_one GET request with request with some_cookie="abc" and
   response with some_cookie="def"
2. /request_one POST request  with
   request with some_cookie="def" and response with some_cookie="ghi"
   and a 303 redirect to /request_xxx
3. /request_xxx GET request with
   request with some_cookie="def"

I am trying to find out why did the 3rd request use cookie "def" instead of updated value "ghi"

Key point here is that, it occurs when I go via elastic load balancer and nginx router. 
Same flow using internal URL without nginx router in-between, works fine

It looks like, before the cookie is set by the response, redirect request is created. This is a normal scenario in my application where I update the cookie and perform redirect-303.

From my finding, increase in cookie size in-turn increases response, What are the nginx configurations affecting the request and response size limits. I don't see any error in nginx error log though

Is there a way to debug from 2nd step response to 3rd redirect request in chrome?

Updating same issue with logs when executed the request via curl
this is what I see when ran via curl

- Ignoring the response-body
- Connection #0 to host application_url left intact
- Issue another request to this URL: 'https://application_url/contextpath/request_xxx'
- Disables POST, goes with GET
- Found bundle for host application_url: xxxxxxxxxxxx
- Re-using existing connection! (#0) with host application_url
- Connected to application_url (IP_HERE) port 443 (#0)

Comment: As to the redirect debugging in Chrome, check the `Preserve log` box in the Network panel of the DevTools.

Comment: Thanks Alexander. I have already checked Preserve log. Thats how I found that the 3rd request does not have the updated cookie value. So here I want a way to stop at 2nd step and get curl request from it. So I can invoke 3rd request using curl with --verbose.

Comment: Can I disable 303 redirects in chrome?

Comment: Since Chrome is a w3c-compliant browser, I don't think you can. But if you wish, you can use curl to run all the steps manually.

Comment: Could this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32219664/asp-net-mvc-api-set-cookie-then-302-303-redirect-loses-the-cookie be of any help for you?

Comment: Path is set correctly in my case

Answer (score 1):

Finally found that, it was cookie size which caused the issue.
Based on the following site, chrome has limitation up to 4096 and I was passing 4116.

http://browsercookielimits.iain.guru/

Why I got carried away with nginx was that when used via internal url, it worked. But that was not the issue.

So one thing to understand is that chrome does not complain when the cookie size exceeds limit. It just doesn't use it while creating next request

Comment: So be aware of cookie monster (as my colleague describes :)) and remember one mantra **To support most browsers, then don't exceed 50 cookies per domain, and don't exceed 4093 bytes per domain** as described in http://browsercookielimits.squawky.net/